# Bedeutung des Wortes komisch

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Bis jetzt hatte er hauptsächlich Mädchen kennen gelernt, nett waren die schon, wenn man Leute mag, die einen bei jedem Satz anfassen. Mädchen, die aussehen wie dreißig und doch so alt waren wie er, seit Monaten unterwegs, die Mädchen, **da werden sie komisch**. (Quelle: *Hauptsache Weit*, Sibylle Berg)

Dieser Abschnitt erzieht die Erlebnisse eines zwanzigjährigen Manns, der durch Asien reist.
Ich verstehe nicht, was der Autor beim ”**da werden sie komisch**“ bedeuten würde, also warum ist sie komisch? Was bedeutet „da“ in diesem Zusammenhang?

Ich hoffe, ich habe genügende Kontexte angeboten.

Comment: Der Titel der Frage ist nichtssagend. Besser wäre z.B. "Bedeutung des Wortes **komisch**".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Humor hat in vielen Fällen etwas mit Überraschung, mit dem Unerwarteten zu tun. Bei vielen Witzen besteht die Pointe darin, dass die Auflösung gerade *nicht* das ist, was man erwarten würde.

Entsprechend gibt es in zumindest einer ganzen Reihe von Sprachen Begriffe, die diese beiden Bedeutungen verbinden. Im Englischen beispielsweise kann "funny" einerseits "lustig" bedeuten, andererseits auch "eigenartig" oder "seltsam":

> This TV show was funny.

> This leftover smells funny, maybe we shouldn't eat it anymore.

Im Französischen gibt es « drôle », das eine ähnliche Rolle einnimmt.

Im Deutschen hat "komisch" diese Funktion. Der Satz

> Die Mädchen werden komisch.

heißt deshalb (meistens) nicht, dass die Mädchen lustig werden, sondern dass sie merkwürdig werden. Die lange Reise ("seit Monaten unterwegs") führt offenbar nach Ansicht des Sprechers dazu, dass die Mädchen sich in irgendeiner Form ungewöhnlich verhalten, ungewöhnlich reagieren oder etwas in dieser Art.

Comment: Vermutlich ist nicht gemeint, dass die Mädchen im Laufe der Zeit in einem wie auch immer gearteten "objektiven" Sinn merkwürdig werden, sondern dass dem Protagonisten im Laufe seiner langen Reise das Verhalten der Mädchen als merkwürdig *bewusst* wird.

Comment: @PaulFrost Das ist möglich, allerdings ist aus dem vorhandenen Kontext nicht vollkommen klar, wer denn nun seit Monaten unterwegs ist und deswegen Grund hätte, "komisch" zu werden- Das könnte "er", "die Mädchen" oder beide sein.

Comment: @tofro Stimmt, ich habe tatsächlich nicht bemerkt, dass mit "seit Monaten unterwegs" auch die Mädchen (und nicht wie ich dachte der Protagonist) gemeint sein können. Vermutlich hat mich das "er" vor dem Nebensatz zu meiner Annahme gebracht.